# Unix File Permissions - Does Write Imply Read?

Tags: unix, file-permissions

If a file had write permissions only, how could a user exercise his right to edit the file if he could not read it?

Does 'write' imply 'read' in Unix?

Comment: Not really. You can test it doing `chmod 722` to a file and then assigning to another user. You will be able to `echo "hello" > file` but not to `cat file`.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting that it creates a situation in which users can blindly make edits and not see what the results are. This is the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Ideally the permissions should be like russian Matryoshka dolls, without write if not read, but extreme cases can be performed. I cannot think in a case in which this situation can be practical.

Comment: I had to Google a picture and think about your analogy for a minute. Nice one!

Answer (score 7):

1. You may be blind and still be able to write:

   ```
    $ touch a
    $ chmod 0200 a
    $ ls -ln  a
    --w------- 1 1000 1000 4 Jul 19 15:13 a
    $ cat a
    $ cat: a: Permission denied
    $ echo "secret message" >> a
    $ chmod 0400 a
    $ cat a
    secret message
   ```
2. Nope :)

Comment: You can use four spaces in front of your code lines to make them be formatted. No need for `br`.

Answer (score 7):

Read, write, execute permissions in Unix/Linux are independent.  It's possible to have write permissions without the read permission.  For *binary* files, you might have seen that read permission isn't granted but execute permission enables you to execute it.  On the other hand, a shell script or any other file that needs to be *interpreted* needs read permissions in order to execute.

Simply providing write permissions without read would enable you to write (also delete) the file without being able to read it.

The following should be self-explanatory:

```
$ touch foo
$ ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 devnull devnull 0 Jul 19 12:00 foo
$ chmod -r foo
$ ls -l foo
--w--w---- 1 devnull devnull 0 Jul 19 12:00 foo
$ cat foo
cat: foo: Permission denied
$ echo hey > foo
$ ls -l foo
--w--w---- 1 devnull devnull 4 Jul 19 12:00 foo
$ cat foo
cat: foo: Permission denied
$ > foo
$ ls -l foo 
--w--w---- 1 devnull devnull 0 Jul 19 12:00 foo
$ rm -f foo 
$ ls -l foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

A file can be a lot of things in unix-like systems. It might, for example be a pipeline, where a user might submit data to, but not receive data from. So no, a write permission does not imply read.

Another example might be a directory where the user can deposit data (potentially destroying existing data), but not read what others have deposited.

Comment: I'm unsure about the write-only directory: writing to a file would need to test for its existance (when opening the file for writing, the system will implicitely check for its existance), so I would think the directory should at least be `chmod +wx` if you want to write in it, have you actually made tests with a write-only directory (I might just be wrong)?

Answer (score 1):

1) write only means write only - so, no way to do so
2) No

Comment: Thank you for putting more into your response.

Comment: @ElwoodHopkins - I answered the first question (on the subject line) and then re-read the question and edited to answer both questions in the question body